When a SQL LIMIT clause executes? (Postgresql)
I'm using Postgres. Suppose I have only one record that satisfies the query parameters. My friend claims that I can speed up query completion if I use limit=1; This is true? GPT Chat also states that the database will stop searching once the limit is met. But I couldn't find any confirmation by googling.
I was also sure that the limit is applied only at the very end of the query execution, after the records have been formed.

For what it's worth, ChatGPT and similar tools perform statistical analysis on texts. They don't "understand" anything they talk about.

Note that tables have rows, not records.

This question is missing all details. A query and a query can be very different things. There is no way anybody can claim that LIMIT 1 will speed up a query. It depends on the query, but you didn't share any query. No query plan either. If you need some advice about improving a query, at least share the DDL for all tables and indexes involved, and the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your SQL statement. And the SQL statement itself. All in plain text, never as an image.

@jarlh Note that, strictly speaking,  relations have tuples!

@Vérace, I'm talking SQL terminology. (Tables/rows/columns.)

I comcur with Tim that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty meaningless. Also, LIMIT is normally executed as the last step of the query (but it will keep subsequent results from being computed).
Anyway, while adding LIMIT to a query that has only a single result row won't change the query result, it can influence the way in which PostgreSQL computes the result, so it can influence the performance of the query (the execution plan). With LIMIT, PostgreSQL will prefer execution plans that return the first rows quickly.
If everything is as it should be, PostgreSQL will estimate the result row count correctly and choose the best execution plan, regardless if you use LIMIT or not. But the optimizer can get it wrong, and then the LIMIT can be a hint to get it on the right track.
In case of doubt, examine the execution plans with EXPLAIN.

wow, thx!! And if the number of rows matching the conditions is greater than the limit, will Postgres continue searching when the limit is reached?

As I think I wrote, no.

First of all, using LIMIT <N> without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless, as there needs to be some logical order from which to select/retain the top N records.
The LIMIT operation is evaluated dead last in the query pipeline, even after ORDER BY.  In the case of your query, which generates just a single record result set, it should not even matter if you add an ORDER BY and LIMIT, because:

Since there is just one record, the ORDER BY sort will be skipped
Since there is just one record, doing LIMIT 1 will also be skipped

In general, for a non empty result set, adding an ORDER BY clause will increase running time, because it instructs Postgres to do a sort operation.

On top of what's already been said... Limit without order may have its usages, being aware that it picks arbitrary records, not "random" records (note the subtle difference) but when you know in advance that query can only return one row it's definitively the wrong tool: either you have a unique index (thus limit doesn't add any value) or you're missing it (thus not having a real guarantee).

This is what I think the question is about: With LIMIT 1, will Postgresql stop reading the table(s) when the first matching row has been returned, or will Postgresql continue reading table data?

@jarlh But the OP has revealed that actual result set size is also 1.

Thank you all! And if the number of records matching the conditions is greater than the limit, will Postgres continue searching when the limit is reached? @TimBiegeleisen
Based on the above, it seems that no

@TimBiegeleisen, yes, the 1 row result set size is known by the user, but the dbms doesn't know that - so the dbms will still keep looking for more data to return.
